# Find length of zlibstream or find unconsumed data by stream

Tags: c#, zlib

Essentially I have data without header information and no padding placed back to back in a file, I know the first entry in the file is a zlib stream which reads successfully however I'm having quite a bit of trouble finding the data after it.

I know in python (example below taken from the official page) they have an unused_data to return the rest of the input stream that wasn't consumed, does anyone know of a c# library that support the same feature or that it supports returning the offset of the adler32 checksum etc.

```
import zlib

lorem = open('lorem.txt', 'rt').read()
compressed = zlib.compress(lorem)
combined = compressed + lorem

decompressor = zlib.decompressobj()
decompressed = decompressor.decompress(combined)

print 'Decompressed matches lorem:', decompressed == lorem
print 'Unused data matches lorem :', decompressor.unused_data == lorem
```

Comment: [ZipFile Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile)

Comment: @Bakudan ZIP files aren't the same thing as Zlib/Deflate compression (though zips optionally do use deflate compression).

Comment: @AKX I missed the question mark. Well anyway .Net has [DeflateStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream) as well, but this what it has.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic.ZLib (which is simply part of DotNetZip) has a `TotalIn` property that you can use to find out how many bytes were read :

```
using System.Text;
using Ionic.Zlib;

using var inputStream = File.Open("Lorem.txt", FileMode.Open);
using var combined = new MemoryStream();
using (var compressor = new ZlibStream(combined, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true))
{
    inputStream.CopyTo(compressor);
}
inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
inputStream.CopyTo(combined);
using var decompressed = new MemoryStream();
combined.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
long totalIn;
using (var decompressor = new ZlibStream(combined, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true))
{
    decompressor.CopyTo(decompressed);
    totalIn = decompressor.TotalIn;
}
byte[] decompressedBytes = decompressed.ToArray();
string decompressedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Decompressed matches lorem: " + (decompressedText == "lorem"));
using var unused = new MemoryStream();
combined.Seek(totalIn, SeekOrigin.Begin);
combined.CopyTo(unused);
byte[] unusedBytes = unused.ToArray();
string unusedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unusedBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Unused data matches lorem: " + (unusedText == "lorem"));
```